# query using SOME in mysql not giving expected results.?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table :

```
start_range           end_range

  1                      4
  4                      8
```

I want the result to be true if it is greater than any of the value of start_range and less than any of the corresponding end_range.

Eg.

value 2 should return `true` , as `2>1` and `2<4`
 but value 4 should return `false` in this case as `4>1`  but `4<4` becomes false, as well as 4>4 becomes false for the second case.

I cannot use the query

```
SELECT Sumthing
FROM XYZ
WHERE value> SOME(start_range) AND value < SOME(end_range)
```

The problem with the above query is let say value = 4.

Now 4> SOME(start_range) will become true as 4>1. AND

4< SOME(end_range) will also become true as 4<8.

But in actual the comparison should be like `(((4>1)AND(4<4)) OR ((4>4)AND(4<8)))` . It should return false.

One more thing , the above table is not persistent , **I have been creating it in a subquery.Thats why i have been using SOME.**
if still my question isn't clear, mention in comments.

Comment: `some` (or `any`) should be applied to a sub-query. It does not make sense pass a single constant to it. Your query is equivalent to `where value > start_range and value < end_range`. And where does the `6` in  `and 2 < 6` come from? there is no `6` in your example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `xyz` is your table:

```
select (count(*) > 0) as HasMatch
from xyz
where value > start_range and value < end_range;
```

I'm not sure why you are using `some`.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want to use subqueries, and `xyz` is not the table in question.  Perhaps this is what you want:

```
select xyz.*
from xyz
where exists (select 1
              from (<your query here>) t
              where xyz.value > t.start_range and xyz.value < t.end_range
             );
```

Comment: this will not work, as consider example of 4,  4> t.start_range will return true as 4>1  AND 4< t.end_range will also return true as 4<8 ,, but in actual it should return false ,,,

Comment: @sagar . . . That condition would have to be true on the same row, so it is your comment that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN start_range<value and end_range>value
            THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'
       END here_name_to_this_column(optional)
FROM table_name
```

[tutorial link](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/CASE)

Answer (score 0):

```
select (count(*) > 0) as HasMatch 
from (select  IF(start_range<value and end_range>value, true, false ) as value 
from XYZ having value =1) as MatchTable
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb8fc/31)